# adjustPan ScrollView above included layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-softkeyboard, adjustpan

Hey there I'm dealing with some kind of problem showing the *softkeyboard* in some android layout the layout ist organized like this:

```
<RelativeLayout>
     <ScrollView>
       Some stuff here...
     </ScrollView>
   <include ... />
<RelativeLayout>
```

I habe already set `adjustPan` and I have tried some experimental stuff with focusing. But my **content** inside the `ScrollView` is getting hidden by the *included layout* everytime its getting focus.

It may be just a logical problem but how do I tell e.g.: my `EditText` which is in the center of some other stuff like `TextViews`, `ViewPager` etc. to be above the included layout when gaining focus ?